# Network Connection Timed out when I start my Putty session

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, fedora, putty

I was able to connect to my virtual machine with Putty for the last two days:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

But since this morning I get :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Do you know what can create this error and how to get rid of it? IP change?

This virtual machine is a Fedora that for the moment is going very well.

Here is the ifconfig of the Fedora machine I want to connect to:

```
[ac@localmachine data-tools]$ ifconfig
br-4bcf98dfca2a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.29.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.29.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:eff:fe64:a9fd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:0e:64:a9:fd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:0f:72:db:f7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.153.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.153.255
        inet6 fe80::75d0:2219:7b3b:97c4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:c8:b8:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 671764  bytes 836534330 (797.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 139028  bytes 17062558 (16.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 196184  bytes 31675520 (30.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 196184  bytes 31675520 (30.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth0d56971: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::605d:1eff:fe75:6bea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 62:5d:1e:75:6b:ea  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 86913  bytes 10046500 (9.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 87236  bytes 20449239 (19.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:71:e2:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Is it because I need to redirect the external TCP port 4662 to port 22 on your local machine? How to do that?

My firewall is up and running. I downed everythong and still had the problem.

But even if I delete them all I still have the same problem.

Now I want to know if the SSH server is running on fedora. So I tried:

```
root@localmachine ac]# sudo service httpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status httpd.service
○ httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor pr>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
```

But it doesn't seem to be related to the SSH server. Then I tried to check if the sshd process is running:

```
[root@localmachine ac]# ps aux | grep sshd
root        5787  0.0  0.1  30536  6656 ?        Ss   Jul08   0:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
root       48866  0.0  0.0 221528   788 pts/0    S+   13:18   0:00 grep --color=auto sshd
```

Y saber si esta escuchando el port 22:

```
[root@localmachine ac]# netstat -plant | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5787/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      5787/sshd: /usr/sbi
```

Then I tried to unhack with the Firewall on the VM side:

```
systemctl disable firewalld;
```

But the error persists.

Comment: There's either an issue with the route to your VM _(wrong IP, VM firewall blocking the connection, etc.)_, the SSH server isn't running, or the wrong port is being connected to _(likely not the latter if you've connected to it via SSH before)_.

Comment: Thanks for your comment **ip**: @JW0914 it doesn't seem to be the wrong IP as the inet of ens33 seems to be 192.168.153.128, which is the same in Putty. **firewall**: I am trying to remove the VM firewall, with the commands I show above but the error persists. **ssh server running**: it seems to run from what I see in `ps aux | grep sshd`   and to listen from the output of `netstat -plant | grep :22`. **wrong port**: I was able to connect it via SSH before ... :/

Comment: I think you might be looking for `systemctl status sshd`.  Other info that may help to understand your problem: host OS,  hypervisor (VMware?, VirtualBox?, ...?), what changed after two days on the Host/Guest OS?